# JAVAFX secondary panels

Tags: java, javafx

Hi guys a little programmer java Swing and I'm trying a new technology like JavaFx just that I just can not figure out how to make operations for navigation between views, in particular.

1. How can I replace a main view on the stage? for example I have a view that I associate with the calback start method in the scene in the following way

   ```
   @Override
   public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
       vistaPrincipale.load();
       Scene scene = new Scene(vistaPrincipale.getRoot());
       primaryStage.setScene(scene);
       primaryStage.show();
   }
   ```

   and during the execution of the program I would like to change the view one with the view two, only that I could not really understand how I did not even find enough material to solve the problem, in swing it was enough to change the frame content bread
2. another problem that I have encountered is to launch a secondary panel like a jdialog in swing, I solved this problem by creating a new stage and using it in the following way, but to be honest it really seems like a very bad solution

   ```
   public class InfoAutori {

       private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(InfoAutori.class);

       private Stage stage;

       public void init(){
           FXMLLoader load = new FXMLLoader();
           Parent root = new AnchorPane();
           try {
               root = load.load(getClass().getResourceAsStream("InfoAutori.fxml"));
           } catch (Exception e) {
               LOGGER.error("Si e' verificato un errore del tipo: " + 
               e.getLocalizedMessage());
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
           stage = new Stage();
           Scene scene = new Scene(root);
           stage.setScene(scene);
       }

       public void visualizza(){
           stage.showAndWait();
       }



   }
   ```

Comment: 1. You can just replace the root of the scene: `scene.setRoot(newUI);` where `newUI` is any instance of `Parent` (e.g. something you get from loading an FXML file). 2. Use a [`Dialog`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/scene/control/Dialog.html). (Though there's nothing particularly wrong with what you posted.)

Comment: http://code.makery.ch/blog/javafx-dialogs-official/

Comment: Other than switching out root node, you can also switch out scenes. Sometimes you would want to create new `Stage` (window), open that new stage and close the current one. One mistake frequently made is that people share nodes across two scenes, it's likely to give you exceptions if you do that.

Comment: Thanks for the help I then provoted and I found the following problems!

1 using the dialog I can not replace the entire panel with a form Esterda in Fxml and also the dialog does not close with the X at the top!

2. So I tried to use an internship making it modal and to solve an exception that raised me when I went to close and reopen the form I had to create the Init method during the Caricsmento of the form in Fxml, then in the Init method I loaded the form-> I created the Scene-> I created the stage every time I wanted to display the form!